# How To Make A Powershell Script Executable in Git via git update-index

Tags: windows, git, powershell

So I am trying to change the Powershell Scripts as executable and commit them as such with an updated index. Is there a way I can do this?

I know in bash it's fairly easy:

```sh
sudo chmod +x some_file.sh
git update-index --chmod=+x some_file.sh
git add -A
git commit -a
git push
```

Any thoughts on how I can do this for Powershell Scripts within Windows Machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Unix, you don't need any special command apart from `git add`, git can detect the executable bit from the worktree. `git diff` even lists mode changes.

On Windows, you can use `git add --chmod +x file`.

You can use `git ls-files --stage` to see which files are executable.